# mvc - submit text input field when enter

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, input, signalr

I'm trying to use "Enter" in a text input field to submit the message (in SignalR chat). I've tried hundreds of methods, but can't seem to get it working.

I either wanna have it so when I press enter it clicks the btn or presses tab then enter.

here is the input and btn

```
<input class="form-control" id="message" maxlength="200" />

<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<input type="button" ...
```

To

```
<input type="submit" ...
```

or

```
<button type="submit" ...
```

See also [button type](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp) documentation.

Comment: @CAMELYON - make sure you wrap your form with the [form](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp) element.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use form submit, you can define the logic in javascript,

```
document.getElementById("message")                    // to get the text box
  .addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {          // Keyup -> Any key pressed
    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {                          // 13 for enter
      document.getElementById("sendmessage").click();
    }
  });
```

For keycodes, you can refer [this](http://keycode.info/) site